# Test method that modifies private array with Swift and XCTest

Tags: ios, swift, xctest

I'm trying to write the tests for a project I've been working on and I can't seem to figure out how to test some of my methods. So, some of the methods modify a private property (Array) by adding or removing items to the array. How can I test this cases?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Basically you are asking how to test a private property.

**NOTE: This approach only works against Framework targets**

If your class inherit from NSObject you should check here: http://saulmora.com/2015/01/15/unit-testing-in-swift-without-access-levels.html

Answer (score 1):

How about opening up your private properties and methods in an extension and only use that for testing. Remove the extension (comment it out) when not testing.

Here I put a 'T' in front of the private method or property name in the extension.

For example:

```
class MyClass {
  private var privateString: String?

  private func privateSetName(name: String) {

    privateString = name
  }

extension MyClass {  // for testing only

  var TprivateString: String? {
    get {
      return self.privateString
    }
  }

  func TprivateSetName(name: String) {
    privateSetName(name)
  }
}
```

then in your XCTest you can do:

```
func testThatNameIsSet() {

  let myClass = MyClass()

  myClass.TprivateSetName("myName")

  XCTAsserNotNil(myClass.TprivateString, "Name should be set.") 
}
```